# How to get y-axis to interact with Bokeh and Hovertool?

Tags: python, graph, bokeh, interactive

I'm trying to get my HoverTool to show the values for bars on the y-axis. It is showing ??? instead which is weird. Further, if anyone knows how, is there a way to have the y-axis not be in scientific notation with the e?

This is the code:

```
#RQ Do people who are scared about a loss of privacy own less devices than those who are not?
output_notebook()

categories = ['The Loss of Privacy', "We'll all lose touch with one another", "We'll all be less safe", "I have no fears about a more connected future", "Other"]

#Interactivity
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[
    ("Biggest Fear", "@x"),
    ("Number of Devices Owned", "@y"),
])

p = figure(x_range = categories, plot_height = 250, plot_width = 1000, title = "Total Devices Owned", tools = [hover])
p.vbar(x = categories, top = [268252,133344,86014,44688,47270], width = 0.5)

p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.y_range.start = 0
p.y_range.end = 300000

p.xaxis.axis_label = "What is your biggest fear as we move towards a more connected future?"
p.yaxis.axis_label = "Amount of Devices Owned"

show(p)
```

And the Graph:
[image: Graph]

Answer (score 0):

You need two changes in your code. First, to show the value on your HoverTool, replace "@y" by "@top". Second, add this line after the "figure" line to get out the scientific notation:  p.left[0].formatter.use_scientific = False

```
#RQ Do people who are scared about a loss of privacy own less devices than those who are not?
output_notebook()

categories = ['The Loss of Privacy', "We'll all lose touch with one another", "We'll all be less safe", "I have no fears about a more connected future", "Other"]

#Interactivity
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[
    ("Biggest Fear", "@x"),
    ("Number of Devices Owned", "@top"),
])

p = figure(x_range = categories, plot_height = 250, plot_width = 1000, title = "Total Devices Owned", tools = [hover])
p.left[0].formatter.use_scientific = False ## This line is to get out scientific notation
p.vbar(x = categories, top = [268252,133344,86014,44688,47270], width = 0.5)

p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.y_range.start = 0
p.y_range.end = 300000

p.xaxis.axis_label = "What is your biggest fear as we move towards a more connected future?"
p.yaxis.axis_label = "Amount of Devices Owned"

show(p)
```